# How do I keep the default site alive in Apache after enabling virtual hosts?

Tags: linux, apache

I have installed Apache 2.4 on a brand new aws linux server instance.  I have defined 2 virtual hosts in conf.d/vhosts.conf and they work fine.  I have seen many people asking about how to access the default site once virtual hosts are defined, I am still having that issue after trying all solutions.  IPADDRESS is replacing my actual IP.

```
DocumentRoot is defined in httpd.conf as /var/www/html
ServerName is IPADDRESS:80
```

in my vhosts file, I created a default virtualhost at the top pointing to the default directory

```
<VirtualHost IPADDRESS:80>
ServerName IPADDRESS
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

..two other functioning virtual hosts

I have also tried this using the * in the virtual host definition

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName IPADDRESS
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

The first virtual host is still bypassed when accessing the server by IP.  The log files haven't shown me anything useful so far.  Where can I look to find the problem?

Comment: I'm no expert on apache, but I had a similar problem when migrating to version 2.4. Try to place the default site in `sites-enabled/000-default.conf` with *:80 and no ServerName. And put the other VirtualHost each in one file under `sites-enabled`, for example, `sites-enabled/site1.conf` with *:80 and ServerName. This is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use a name instead of IPADRESS in the ServerName directive.

`<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName www.example.com
</VirtualHost>`

You can read more here https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servername

Hope it helps